# Vue - reset v-model variable after a content is added

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this code in a parent component of a vue app

```html
<template>
    <div class="container-fluid" id="editorWrapper">
        <div class="row mt-5 pt-4 m-0">
            <PostEditor 
                ref="editor"
                :v-model="sectionTitle" 
                v-model:cover="programCover" 
                v-model:content="programContent"
            >
            </PostEditor>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

It will listen for events that are called from the `<ProgramEditor>` component, where I have a method that is responsable to add new post sections into an array of object with the following code

```js
        addSection() {
            console.log(this.$refs.editor.$refs.programEditor.getHTML())
            this.sections.push({ 
                sectionTitle: this.sectionTitle,
                sectionBody: this.programContent 
            })
            this.sectionTitle = ''
            this.$refs.editor.$refs.programEditor.setHTML('')
        }
```

Into the `<PostEditor>` component where I've used vue-quill, I have this code

```html
<template>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9 p-0 mb-3" id="programEditorWrapper">
        <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 rounded-0" id="" placeholder="Title" @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)">
        <label class="mb-1" for="programCover">
        <QuillEditor ref="programEditor" theme="snow" content-type="html" toolbar="full" @update:content="$emit('update:content', $event)"></QuillEditor>
    </div>
</template>
```

I need to reset the title input field when a new post section is added, but I'm not able to achive this by setting the `sectionTitle` variable in this way

```js
this.sectionTitle = ''
```

How I can achive this and have the input field resetted when the user add a new post section?

Comment: vue2 or vue3? you forgot to add one of those which are required when adding vue.js tag

Comment: Don't you just need to add `:value={value}` property to the input?

Comment: @Bravo I'm using vue 3

Comment: @MichałSadowski can you show an example please?I'm not sure to understand what do you mean.

Comment: @user9741470 in the `PostEditor` you can do `<input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 rounded-0" id="" placeholder="Title" :value={modelValue} @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)">` because, right now, this input only emits the data but doesn't accept changes from the parent. See also https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#usage-with-v-model

Comment: ok, so I will be not able to reset it programmatically from the parent component right?